# What circuit element must be removed to have the VTh equal to the voltage between two points using Thevenin's Theorem?

Tags: thevenin

The question that I'm trying to understand is provided below:

> The Thevenin's equivalent of the circuit "around" 6 ohms has a VTh equal to the voltage between a & b,
>
> (a) With the 6 ohms and all sources (independent and dependent) removed.
>
> (b) With the 6 ohms removed between a & b.
>
> (c) With the 6 ohms remain connected between a & b.

Diagram:

[image]

I assume that the answer is **b**. When I removed the 6-ohm resistor, both \$v_{a}\$ and \$v_{b}\$ are 10 V; the resulting \$v_{Th}\$ would be zero. I think that this is how you find the Thevenin equivalent looking into terminals *a* and *b*.

Also, if my answer is going to be letter A, I think that it is unnecessary for determining the voltage. My further readings suggest that turning off the independent sources is only considered when calculating for resistance.

What I thought about letter C is that it is the wrong answer since I cannot apply Thevenin's theorem without turning off anything at all.

Do we have the same thoughts?

Comment: Yes, B is the correct answer.

Comment: Yaaay! Thankiez!